# Paypal integration with Yii

Tags: paypal

This is my Directory Structure in yii

Project-Name

```
   Source Files
       Protected
         ->controlleres
         ->Vendors
```

In vendors I have paypal merchant sdk.

In controller I have written an action which calls setExpressCheckout, but I am getting the following error :

include(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am having problem with setting path for the php files for merchant sdk which I am using in my code